# Verifing user touched links before a Cocoa Touch Webview can begin the load

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, cocoa-touch, webview

I had a potential client ask me if I can prevent a user navigating away from their website within an iPad app? So I would need to load the client site within a web view and somehow disable invalid links i.e. banners and promotional links.

I am wondering if there is a way to catch the link that has been touched within the view before it is loaded.

If there is no way to do this, is there away to strip a web page of invalid links before it is loaded into the web view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. It's called when user taps a link. Return `NO` if you don't want to handle any links or `YES` if you want your web view to handle the request. More info in Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

A nice thing is to filter out some requests and handle them yourself based on e.g. URL-scheme of the request or based on `UIWebViewNavigationType` value. Note: for a filtered requests that you handle, you still return `NO`.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I will look into this immediately.